# Objective-C: Partial update of object in realm

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, realm

The problem: I'm using Realm along the AFNetworking library. To keep things clean I'm working with custom serializers parsing incoming json responses and mapping them to objects. The returned objects a than saved, updated or in some cases forwarded. The problem is that some relations get overwritten and I need to execute a kind of partial update.

Is there a way in realm to copy a persisted object and add its values to a non-persisted object, updated with response values only?

**Example:**

*Current state:*

```
cat{
   name: "kitty"
   owners: ["peter"] 
}
```

*Incoming Response:*

```
cat{
    name:"pussy"
    owner:[]
}
```

**Wanted Result:**

```
cat{
    name:"pussy"
    owner:["peter"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We JUST updated [that section of the Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#creating-and-updating-objects-with-primary-keys) to clarify this behaviour.

Unfortunately, because 'nil' is also a valid value for every optional property of a Realm object, it's not possible for Realm to intelligently tell the difference between when an empty value supplied should be ignored, or should be used to empty the property it's pointing at.

The easiest way would be to use the JSON you've received to build an `NSDictionary` that only contains the value you wish to update, and then pass that to Realm through the `+[RLMObject createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:]` to explicitly only update the properties on that object that you've supplied.

If you want to update your object using a `RLMObject` copy of that object, you'll need to make sure the copy contains all of the properties you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks TiM, yes that would be a solution, however as already told I'm using Serializers to map this objects and in some cases they are getting persisted in others not. Therefore I'm using the initWithVlaue: constructor. Is there a way to copy a persisted object in a smart manner? or get all the properties and its values as a Dictionary at the state of the art?

Comment: My pleasure Peter! While Realm itself doesn't provide copying capability just yet, I just did some research and found there's a third party library to help manage working with Realm and JSON: https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON

From the looks of it, `initWithValue:` is somewhat restrictive in the way it works right now, and there's an issue open to improve it: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2377